# AngularJS loading page with unrelated data from controller (2 GETS or only 1?)

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page, rendered by an angularjs controller, that shows the details of a user on page load.
This list is given by the controller of Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contact/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public User getContact(@PathVariable String id) {
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    return user;
}
```

Which is requested by angularjs inside a details controller:

```
$http.get(urlBase+'/contact/'+$routeParams.userid).success(function(data) {
    $scope.user = data;
});
```

Now I also want to show, on the same page, other details such as whether the visitor on that page is friends with that user. This information should be loaded while the page loads (same as retrieving the details of the user)

Should I use a separate get method to do this kind of check and put it under the first get method for example? E.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/isFriends/{userId}",  method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public RETURNWHAT loadProfile(@PathVariable String userId, RequestParameter request) {
    /*
     * Do some checks whether a user is friends with the user on the page.
     */
     request.setParameter("isFriends", true); //Perhaps not a good idea to use set parameter to retrieve this inside the angularjs' controller?
}
```

Other get:

```
$http.get(urlBase+'/isFriends/' + $routeParams.userid).success(function(data) {

});
```

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

I thought of only calling 1 get method that retrieves this information from 1 method in the controller. But then I assume that the controller has to send back a map with all the details.

Edit:

I believe using 1 method in the controller of Spring which returns a `Map<String, Object>` and 1 get function in angularjs should be the best option, am I correct?

Comment: yes 1 call is good way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment mate. Just to clarify, so my edit (where I use the Map<String, Object> would be better, correct?

Comment: Yes, you should always minimize no of http requests from your site.

Comment: Thank you mate. If you comment (post answer) I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: Instead of `Map<String, Object>` you might want to return a wrapper object that contains both `User` and whatever `loadProfile` returns.

Comment: @stholzm I appreciate your comment mate. That might be a good idea indeed. I assume that is much faster?

Comment: yeah something like {user:{id:"1", name:"a", address:"abc", isfriends:true, country: "XYZ"}}

Comment: @Moody No, I don't think the performance impact is even measurable. Just thought it would be a cleaner solution to your problem. I elaborated an answer, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually is a trade off between no of http requests and amount data being sent back from server, so as specific to your user case, its just one field you want, piggybacking to existing response is better way than making two requests.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @vinayakj that it is more efficient to combine the data in one HTTP request (less server load, less bandwidth). Definitely makes sense if you expect alot of these requests. But instead of adding the "isFriends" information to `User`, I'd wrap both in an "aggregate" object:

```
class UserDetails {
    User user;
    boolean isFriends;
}
```

The resulting JSON might look like this:

```
{
    user: {
        id: 1,
        name: "abc"
    },
    isFriend: true
}
```

Why not just adding "isFriends" to `User`? Because what we are doing here is solely a webservice performance optimization. It should not make your model less maintainable.

Why not `Map<String, Object>`? Those maps are pretty generic - it would be harder to see which response contains which kind of data. A dedicated class adds type-safety and documentation. Also, you may want to annotate the components separately.

The obvious drawback is that you need to create extra classes with somewhat funny names.

Comment: This seems acceptable but can't really comment on the structures of beans that are needed use, with the information available in question.